# how to calculate nth term of mth row of this table?

Tags: c++

there is a table which grows as

```
1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3,3
1,1,4,4,6
1,1,5,5,10,10
1,1,6,6,15,15,20
.....and so on
```

If i want to find an specific element of the table like if I want to find 4th element of 6th row then the answer will be 6 but if I want to find the nth element of mth row for any n>=1 m>=1 then how to do it?

Comment: Are you asking about the formula which creates the numbers? If so, you might consider asking at math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

These numbers look like binomial coefficients, so this "table" could be [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) row-wise re-ordered by size.

Though, this is just one of the infinitely many "tables" that'd start like this. If you don't name a specific production rule or another way to deduce arbitrary values of the "table", there's no way telling for sure which of those infinitely many "tables" you have here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to hold the values in a kind of table without wasting memory by for example giving each line more slots than necessary.

To do that I'd suggest a vector of vectors (assuming your values are integers):

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > table;
```

Provided you are sure that a value at (m, n) exists you can get it with:

```
int value = table[m][n];
```

(Note that m and n count from 0.)

If you're not sure use the safer

```
int value = table.at(m).at(n);
```

which will throw an exception if (m, n) doesn't exist.

To add a row you could call

```
table.resize(table.size() + 1);
```

and to add a column to a row

```
table[m].resize(table[m].size() + 1);
```

I'd recommend to put the table into the protected or private section of a special class and add functions to access the elements as needed.